# How to add UITextView in CCLayer or CCScene in cocos2d-iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I want to add an instruction page where instruction written in UITextView. How to do it in Cocos2d. Because this is a game page and I want to take menu transaction effects of cocos2d like CCTransitionRadialCCW.

I wrote this code

```
UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,60, 300,360)];
textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
textView.text = @"I am First enemy";
[textView setEditable:NO]; 
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector]openGLView]addSubview:textView];
```

But there is problem that it is added to the main CCDirector page, while I am writing this code

```
 // [[[CCDirector sharedDirector]openGLView]addSubview:textView];
 //  replaced by :-
[self addChild:textView];
```

It gives me error. Please tell me how to add UITextView in CCScene or CCLayer.

I know that [self addChild:(CCNode *)node];

addChild: method needs CCNode so please tell me that how can typecast or convert UITextView object to CCNode.

If there is some alternate option for that please tell me .Like CCLabelTTF is alternate for UILabel, is there alternate for UITableView in Cocos2d-iphone.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at CCTableView: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/archives/943.

Combining UIKit and Cocos2D in such a way that you have the interleaving you have mentioned is likely to be very difficult, because everything done in Cocos2D is drawn in one OpenGL view.  When you add a UIView, you can only add it in front of or behind Cocos2D's view.

Answer (score 0):

No matter which way you're adding the UIView to cocos2d, it will not be animated by the cocos2d transition effects because simply speaking the UIView objects exist outside the OpenGL view that cocos2d uses (and animates in the case of transitions).

Adding UIViews to a cocos2d view as in your first example code is correct. But in order to position the view like a node, you should consider using the [CCUIViewWrapper](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/6889).